# Skip first column

Tags: pandas

Quite simple question I hope.Basically I want the same output without the first column.

```
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils','Kings', 
 'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
    'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
    'Year': 
    [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)
   df.loc[df['Team']=='Riders'].values.tolist()

  Out [1]:
   [['Riders', 1, 2014, 876],
    ['Riders', 2, 2015, 789],
    ['Riders', 2, 2016, 694],
   ['Riders', 2, 2017, 690]]
```

I want my output to be:

```
     Out [1]:
     [[1, 2014, 876],
     [2, 2015, 789],
     [ 2, 2016, 694],
     [2, 2017, 690]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
df.loc[df['Team']=='Riders', ['Rank', 'Year', 'Points'] ].values.tolist()
```

Or if you want to select the columns without explicitly specifying column names,

```
columns = df.columns.values.tolist()[1:]
df.loc[df['Team']=='Riders', columns].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.loc[df.Team == "Riders", df.columns[1:]].to_numpy().tolist()
```

`to_numpy()` is recommended instead of `values` according to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html). Both gives you numpy arrays so you can still use `tolist()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select by positions all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
#pandas 0.24+
print (df.iloc[(df['Team']=='Riders').to_numpy(), 1:].to_numpy().tolist())
#oldier pandas versions
#print (df.iloc[(df['Team']=='Riders').values, 1:].values.tolist())
[[1, 2014, 876], [2, 2015, 789], [2, 2016, 694], [2, 2017, 690]]
```